# Setting up VSCode env for bpy and pylance

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, blender, bpy

I've read like few books worth google results for the past WEEK but I haven't found a single relevant data.
There is plenty of advises how to setup `venv/.env/pythonPath` but none of them work. Here is what I have so far:

1. Python 3.7 installed alongside main installation of 3.8 (no OS path env modified for 3.7 specifically)
2. Installed [bpy wheel](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1uSiTQLvlUxu7PDT2TCT4XIrwGwn1WWph?usp=sharing) package/module
3. Python 3.7 selected as interpreter (offered by VSCode automatically)
4. Set up `.env` inside the project that targets all possible directories with relevant modules
5. Set up env through terminal according to [MS docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments)

Absolutely none of this matters:
[image]

**Pylance** is unable to see imports properly and having 173 import errors in error log kinda gnaws at me at this point.

Comment: Is the module called bpy installed in current environment?